# Adding specific number of rows in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I want to add 11 number of rows after every row. the code which I have made adds only 1 row. I don't know how to add 11 rows to be exact.

```
function addRows(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();

  for (var i = 1; i <= numRows*2 - 1; i+=2) {
   sheet.insertRowAfter(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: Did your issue get solved?

Comment: Yes my issue is resolved now. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're most welcome. Also, please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) that provided a solution to your problem by [clicking the "check mark" button underneath the vote buttons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). This is useful because this community relies on it to share knowledge to other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can specify the number of rows to add by using [insertRowsAfter](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertRowsAfter(Integer,Integer)).
- To avoid the added rows messing up with your loop, you can insert rows in the reverse order. It could be something like this:

```
function addRows(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  for (var i = numRows; i > 0; i--) {
    sheet.insertRowsAfter(i, 11);
  }
}
```

I hope this is of any help.